# jQuery Slider IE Problems (not working)

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://landpros.turnpostinteractive.com/LandPros_Results_2.html

I have a slider on the bottom of the page that is working in every browser but IE8. I can't seem to figure out why its not working in this browser.

Here is my HTML..

```
<div class="row bottom-scroller">  
 <h1>
results <a href="#">view</a>
 </h1>
<div class="demo-mastercon">
<div class="advancedscroller-con">
    <div id="as2" class="advancedscroller" style="width:100%;">
        <ul class="items">
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tobe">
            <img src="images/details-page/property.jpg" alt="property" />
            <p>
                Shawnee County Sanctuary<br/>
                Shawnee County, KS<br/>
                10.91 +/- Acres<br/>
                <span><strong>$369,000</strong> <a href="#">view</a></span>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div><!--/row-->
```

Here is my custom CSS...

```
/***************************************
         ADVANCED SLIDER
 ****************************************/
 .advancedscroller{
height: 100px;
 }

 .advancedscroller-con .thumbsCon{
height: 100px;
}

 .advancedscroller-con ul.thumbsClip{
height: 100px;
}

 .advancedscroller-con li img{ 
float: left; 
padding-right: 12px; 
 }

 .advancedscroller .bulletsCon{
display: none;
 }
```

as well as this file... http://landpros.turnpostinteractive.com/advancedscroller/plugin.css

Finally, here is my jquery...

```
 <!--
**************************
    ADVANCED SCROLLER
**************************
   -->
  <script src="advancedscroller/plugin.dev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#as1").advancedscroller({
        settings_swipe: "on"
        ,design_arrowsize: "40"
        });
    $("#as2").advancedscroller({
        settings_swipe: "on"
        ,design_arrowsize: "40"
        });
    $("#as3").advancedscroller({
        settings_swipe: "on"
        ,design_arrowsize: "40"
        });
    $("#as4").advancedscroller({
        settings_mode: "onlyoneitem"
        ,design_arrowsize: "0"
        ,settings_swipe: "on"
        ,settings_swipeOnDesktopsToo: "on"
        });
     });
   </script>  
  <!--/advancedscroller-->
```

and the plugins file... http://landpros.turnpostinteractive.com/advancedscroller/plugin.dev.js

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use this tag in header of your HTML file.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```